# Mildew in new apartment

Tags: humidity

I am in a newly built apartment. No basement.i see mold on furniture that sits on floor. I have a dehumitifier since Friday. I had it set at 40. In 7 days, I had to empty water 6 times. I then set it at 50. It ran for 2-3 minutes, off for about a minute. Complained to maintenance that something wrong . Where is all this water coming from. They told me to set it at 70. It has not run since. I see it says 63 on dehumitifier, suggestions and advise appreciated. I cringe to see my electric bill. I'm on a fixed income. Should I even consider moving?

live in pa. No mildew was not on furniture prior. Just developed about a month ago. I had dehumitifier set at 40. In 6 days,the dehumitifier was full. I was told all air has water and this is not unusual. I know I've been given runaround by owner. Was told to set at 70. I knew this was not correct. Yes, I have central air, but being on first floor and Windows closed, it was cool and central air did not kick on. I noticed a problem when I had breathing problems and knew something was wrong. Since running dehumitifier a week, I no longer have breathing problems.

Comment: You haven't said where you are. If you're in the middle of the Amazon rain forest, what can be said? There may be some moisture left over from construction (drywall mud, paint, etc.), but it's mostly about your climate. Does the apartment have central air conditioning?

Comment: 70% (or even 63%) relative humidity will probably be quite uncomfortable in the summer, and at that point you risk bacteria flourishing, as well as some of your belongings getting ruined (especially anything made of MDF or particle board). 45-55% is generally pretty comfortable. Too much lower and you risk things drying out too much and a lot of static shocks (and maybe other bacteria). Of course, as @isherwood said, if your climate is regularly 90% humidity, 70% may feel like a relief. All depends on where you are.

Comment: 55% RH is the maximum to avoid mildew, 50% is usually the recommended level. Dehumidifiers are inefficient below about 40%, so you'll spend a lot on electricity without pulling much moisture from the air if the humidity is at that level. Moisture gets absorbed into every porous surface, so if you start with enough moisture to promote mold, you will need to run the dehumidifier for days to dry things out. 40-45% can help initially, but once you get things under control, run it at 50%. It will cycle as needed to keep the humidity below the mildew threshold. Over 60% you'll get new mold blooms.

Comment: @fixer1234: why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: Consider reading [this](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/pdfs/appenc.pdf) first. Whether 70% (or even 63%) RH will promote mold growth or not depends on a lot of things: temperature, ventilation etc.

Comment: Also, mold will not die/dissapear by starving it of water (that will only prevent its expansion). Mold needs to be actively cleared. In your question it isn't clear whether the mold was there when you moved in or whether it grew on your furniture that presumably didn't have it before.

Comment: I live in pa.  Mold grew on furniture after I moved in

Answer (score 1):

Comfort and mold are two different things.  The comments you received are good advice for comfort, but mold has its own considerations, especially if you live in a hot, humid area where interior mold is a prevalent problem.

55% relative humidity is the maximum to avoid mildew; 50% is usually the recommended level.  Dehumidifiers are inefficient below about 40%, so you'll spend a lot on electricity without pulling much moisture from the air if the humidity is at that level.

Moisture gets absorbed into every porous surface, so if you start with enough moisture to promote mold, you will need to run the dehumidifier for days to dry things out. 40-45% can help initially, but once you get things under control, run it at 50%. It will cycle as needed to keep the humidity below the mildew threshold. Over 60% you'll get new mold blooms.

As others have indicated, where you live can be important to knowing whether you have a bigger problem.  If you live in a place like Florida, interior mold comes with the territory and you just need to deal with it.  Mildew caused by environmental humidity will bloom in a widespread pattern.

If you live in a cooler, drier climate, it would be unusual for interior humidity to get that high on its own, so interior mold could be a sign of a water problem (like a leaky water pipe or rain or ground water getting in somewhere).  If you get mold in that situation, it is likely to be concentrated in the problem location.

There's tons of information and advice online.  Here's a link that covers a lot of information in one place, and it's written for a non-technical audience: https://inspectapedia.com/sickhouse/Humidity_Level_Target.php

BTW, @Fizz makes a good point in a comment.  Drying things out doesn't kill the mold, it just controls it.  After a bloom, there will still be spores everywhere waiting to regrow.  You need to clean and disinfect all surfaces to get rid of it.  Vacuuming with a regular vacuum cleaner will just recycle it back into the air; use a HEPA vacuum cleaner (there are consumer models that aren't outrageously expensive).

If you live in an area where interior mold is endemic, consider getting a HEPA filter to capture the airborne spores, which will reduce what's available to bloom if conditions become favorable.  There are HEPA-grade filters for your HVAC system, or high-end pleated "allergy-rated" filters.

Comment: BTW -- mold does *not* have to be a fact of life in Florida.  Read [BSI-037](https://buildingscience.com/documents/insights/bsi-037-mold-in-alligator-alley) if you want your Florida experience to be not-moldy :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, great article!

Answer (score 0):

I live in pa. No mildew was not on furniture prior. Just developed about a month ago. I had dehumitifier set at 40. In 6 days,the dehumitifier was full. I was told all air has water and this is not unusual. I know I've been given runaround by owner. Was told to set at 70. I knew this was not correct. Yes, I have central air, but being on first floor and Windows closed, it was cool and central air did not kick on. I noticed a problem when I had breathing problems and knew something was wrong. Since running dehumitifier a week, I no longer have breathing problems.

Comment: See comment and answer above

Comment: This looks like clarification of the question rather than a solution.  The site is a knowledge base of answers rather than a forum, so it relies on a structure of all information related to the question being in the question, and answer posts being reserved for solutions.  Readers may see this post and think your problem is solved.  Much of the information here is already covered in the question, but it would be better to edit the question to add the additional information and then delete this post.

Comment: BTW, this kind of problem is much more common with houses in a place like Florida than Pennsylvania, but you can get situations like what you describe in northern climates in buildings like apartment buildings with central HVAC that isn't adjusted for each apartment.  It sounds like the owner may just be clueless, doesn't care, or isn't willing to invest in the property to have the system fine-tuned or upgraded.  (cont'd)

Comment: The dehumidifier and cleaning advice in my answer still applies.  You don't control the HVAC filters, but you can get a room-sized HEPA filter or electronic air cleaner, which will make a big difference in breathing problems and help control mold spores.

Comment: if it took 6 days to fill up at 40%, it's not very humid in there, or the machine is weak...